# Can Zizek's big Other be seen as a collective form of "bad faith"?

Tags: existentialism, sartre, zizek

I refer to [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15454/who-is-the-big-other-and-is-there-a-little-other) question to define the big Other for Zizek.
Couldn't the big Other be seen as what enforces the *mauvaise foi* (what makes us behave like we have no choice to avoid existential dread), but at society level instead of individual level?